# how to plot a stock price chart? Why is my result so different from the right one

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

this is my code.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv("data.csv",delimiter=",")
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(data1["date"],data1["close"])
plt.show()
```

this is data looks like.[stock price data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ2vR.png).it has 4158 rows.

this is [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEoUD.png)

and this is what it should be(the blue one).[right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Rc0.png)

it seems like there are too many details lost on my result.

Comment: Hi can you give an example of the code so I can see what you are graphing

Comment: i just added my code. thank you for answering me.

Comment: One of the problems lies on the fact that the data in `data1['date']` is being treated as `int` and not as `datetime`. You have to do some treatment on your dataset before plotting the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eli Lin, before plotting your graph you have to work the `data1['date']`. This column should contain `datetime` objects, instead, it contains `int` objects.

I reproduced part of your dataset, tho, I believe it is more than enough:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': np.arange(0, 14).tolist(),
                      'code' : '000300.SH',
                      'date' : [20050104,20050105,20050106,20050107,20050110,20050111,20050112,20050113,20050114,20050117,20050118,20050119,20050120,20050121],
                      'open' : [994.796,981.577,993.331,983.045,983.760,994.189,996.651,996.078,996.617,979.111,967.374,974.333,963.213,954.462],
                      'close': [982.794,992.564,983.174,983.958,993.879,997.135,996.748,996.877,988.306,967.452,974.689,967.210,956.245,982.604]
})
```

```
data1

  index      code       date       open     close
 0    0 000300.SH   20050104    994.796   982.794
 1    1 000300.SH   20050105    981.577   992.564
 2    2 000300.SH   20050106    993.331   983.174
 3    3 000300.SH   20050107    983.045   983.958
 4    4 000300.SH   20050110    983.760   993.879
 5    5 000300.SH   20050111    994.189   997.135
 6    6 000300.SH   20050112    996.651   996.748
 7    7 000300.SH   20050113    996.078   996.877
 8    8 000300.SH   20050114    996.617   988.306
 9    9 000300.SH   20050117    979.111   967.452
10   10 000300.SH   20050118    967.374   974.689
11   11 000300.SH   20050119    974.333   967.210
12   12 000300.SH   20050120    963.213   956.245
13   13 000300.SH   20050121    954.462   982.600
```

First, lets change the dates into `datetime`:

```
data1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

```
data1

   index         code         date     open    close
 0     0    000300.SH   2005-01-04  994.796  982.794
 1     1    000300.SH   2005-01-05  981.577  992.564
 2     2    000300.SH   2005-01-06  993.331  983.174
 3     3    000300.SH   2005-01-07  983.045  983.958
 4     4    000300.SH   2005-01-10  983.760  993.879
 5     5    000300.SH   2005-01-11  994.189  997.135
 6     6    000300.SH   2005-01-12  996.651  996.748
 7     7    000300.SH   2005-01-13  996.078  996.877
 8     8    000300.SH   2005-01-14  996.617  988.306
 9     9    000300.SH   2005-01-17  979.111  967.452
10    10    000300.SH   2005-01-18  967.374  974.689
11    11    000300.SH   2005-01-19  974.333  967.210
12    12    000300.SH   2005-01-20  963.213  956.245
13    13    000300.SH   2005-01-21  954.462  982.604
```

In order to plot and add some style, you can import some libraries, but its not mandatory:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
```

Now you can plot your chat just by using this:

```
data1.plot(x='date', y='close', figsize=(12,6));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I think i should learn more about pandas. Haah

Comment: @EliLin no problem, we are all learning together.  Just one tip: leave the `answer` field just to anwers, you can comment and ask for further help here, in the comemnts. Now, about your question: it is pretty standard to plot financial data ignoring saturdays, sundays and holidays. It can be problematic if you are mixing stocks and crypto, tho, in the same dataframe. A good way to deal with it is to use some `forward fill` method, in order to repeat stocks prices on days you would not normaly have them.